Importing vs Rendering of custom Web Components in Angular
We are building a native JS web component library (Foo Web Components, or FWC), and we are trying to use it in an Angular application (for now, without a wrapper).

We are packing it as an NPM package, and installing it as a dependency through npm i @foo/foo-web-components.
We are importing the necessary components in a brand new Angular 18 application in a module.
We are attempting to use two components (Input and Datepicker) in a simple app.component.

Our relevant files now look as follow:
app.component.ts:
import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { FWCInput, FWCDatepicker } from '@foo/foo-web-components';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public today: Date = new Date();
  //@ts-ignore
  @ViewChild("datepicker") datepicker: ElementRef<FWCDatepicker>;
  //@ts-ignore
  @ViewChild("input") input: ElementRef<FWCInput>;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.datepicker);
    console.log(this.input);
  }
}

app.component.html:
Datepicker: <fwc-datepicker #datepicker [date]="today" label="Datepicker"></fwc-datepicker>
Input: <fwc-input #input placeholder="placeholder" value="From Template" label="Input"></fwc-input>

With this configuration, the page looks like this:

No errors in the console or build process, but the components aren't in the DOM or rendered.
However, if we add a single line in the constructor of the app.component.ts as so:
  constructor() {
    var foo = new FWCInput();
  }

Suddenly the components appear:

I'm assuming it's got to do with something related to when Angular actually loads an import... If it's "not actually used" (as perceived by the framework) it won't load it.
However, when we import just ONE of the members from the library (in this case, the FWCInput), the whole library gets pulled-in and everything works (including the FWCDatepicker which wasn't referenced in a new variable).
Why is this, and how would we go about as library designers to allow users to just "use" our components without instantiating disposable variables?

EDIT: Removed the fwc.module.ts file since it wasn't needed (came from previous tests...).


Why are you adding FWCDatepicker and FWCInput to your module's providers? This looks wrong to me, they should be removed from there. Not sure though if it solves your problem.

Hi @JSONDerulo: I removed the module... It came from our previous tests trying to find out what worked and what didn't.

I think you just need to add the source code to the root of the application, then the component will begin rendering.
We cannot add the components to providers, since they are just classes, providers array accepts only classes that have the decorator @Injectable().
Only if you import the source code will you be able to use the component is my understanding.
import '@foo/foo-web-components'; // <- changed here
import { FWCInput, FWCDatepicker } from '@foo/foo-web-components';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public today: Date = new Date();
  //@ts-ignore
  @ViewChild("datepicker") datepicker: ElementRef<FWCDatepicker>;
  //@ts-ignore
  @ViewChild("input") input: ElementRef<FWCInput>;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.datepicker);
    console.log(this.input);
  }
}


thanks for that, but... That's now what I usually have to do when using other packages I download. Is it because it's not yet a proper Angular-wrapped library? I would like the consumers to have the best Developer experience, and not have to import stuff in a non-ES way (I'm referring to the import '...'; statements. Does this make sense?

Just as an FYI, removing the module (it came from previous tests and was no longer needed), and adding import '@foo/foo-web-components'; at the beginning of the component file solved the issue. However, I'm hesitant to leave it at that because I feel it's a workaround. Is there something we as the library owners can do to have the consumers not do that import?

@Nelladel Create a wrapper library specific to angular, that is how it goes for most react web component libraries. Its a single line, which DEVs can add easily based on documentation. But CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA is a big NO when the actual end user has to use this. So my suggestion is create a wrapper library which the end users can comsume just like a normal angular project. The wrapper project will contain the import import '@foo/foo-web-components'; so all the ugly stuff is abstracted away by your angular wrapper library

It looks like it has to do with the difference between "side-effect imports" and "named imports", just in case someone else wants to investigate. Thanks Naren, I will approve your answer :) (And yes, the wrapper was phase 2 of the project!)
